# PHP Syntax error, i cant find where

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

Here is the code:

```
while($i != $unisize){
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM suscritos WHERE sector='$uni[$i]' AND oficio='$oficio'";
                $req2 = mysql_query($sql2);
                $co2 = mysql_num_rows($req2);
                        if($co2 == 0){
                            die("Unable to find near you"); 
                        }else{
                            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2){
                            array_push($idarray, $row2['id']);                              
                            }
                        }
                $i++;
        }
```

This is the error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'**
All the other variables have been declared before.
Thanks.

Comment: Some online validator can help you to check where the error is (ideone of php formatter). Although the browser should provide you enough information. Next time, use them before asking here.

Comment: Sorry, im starting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a closing parenthesis here:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2){
```

where it should be:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2)){
```

On the side note, use `mysqli_* prepared statement` rather than the deprecated `mysql_*` to prevent [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: You got it!, i was having a hard time. i cant belive i didnt see it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error message, there is a syntax error in your code.
In order to solve this error, please replace this line:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2) {
```

By the following:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2)){
```

You were missing a closing parenthesis `)` in your `while` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close the while () here:
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2)<<<<<<

Answer (score 0):

Close while loop

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2)
```